# How to only show users of specific groups in scripted user picker based on custom field in Jira?

Tags: javascript, groovy, jira

in jira we need to restrict a user picker field to only show specific users based on a group field. Should be like this:

Every issue contains a group field GROUP which gets automatically set on issue creation. Only people of these specific groups can access and transition an issue over all workflow steps. Every issue contains one group but there are ~50 different groups overall an issue can contain.

In one transition people need to chose a single user from the (scripted) user picker PROCESS OWNER based on the GROUP field above. So the (scripted) field should only show users that are part of the specific group, which is set in the issue.

Thanks in advance.